# VBA, Take interior colour from worksheet 1 and copy to other worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I am new to working with VBA and looking for a function to do the following.

Take the interior colours from Worksheet A0, Cell A1:AK126
Copy interior color only to Worksheet A1, Cell A1:AK126; Worksheet A2, Cell A1:AK126; Worksheet A3, Cell A1:AK126; Worksheet A4, Cell A1:AK126.

I have tried altering code from another answer (copied below) but my VBA knowledge is not good enough to pick it apart.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    total_sheets = wkb.Worksheets.Count
    aff_row = Target.Row
    aff_column = Target.Column
    sheet_used = (aff_column / 2) + 2
    If aff_column > 1 Then
        If Int(sheet_used) = sheet_used Then
            If sheet_used <= total_sheets Then
                wkb.Sheets(sheet_used).Cells(aff_row + 2, 2).Interior.Color = Target.Interior.Color
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub KopyKolor()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    For i = 1 To 4
        shn = "A" & i
        For j = 1 To 126
            For k = 1 To 37
                Sheets(shn).Cells(j, k).Interior.Color = Sheets("A0").Cells(j, k).Interior.Color
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

This does a cell-by-cell color copy.